# gevent + subprocess: Is it possible to patch subprocess used in some of imported modules, for example in sh?

Tags: python, subprocess, gevent

How do I use `sh` (python module) with `gevent`?

If I run suprocess directly I do:

```
import gevent
from gevent.subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
patch_all()

subprocess.Popen(...)
```

But how I can use `sh` with `gevent`?
Say:

```
from sh import tar
tar("cf", "file.tar", "dir")
```

`tar` is just an example, I want to find the answer generally.
Is it possible at all?

How do I patch subprocess that is used in `sh`?

Or more general question:

How do I [patch](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html) `subprocess` if it is used in some of imported modules (like sh)? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Can you please say more about your use case? Are you trying to simply async wait for multiple functions or actually share data between them?

Comment: @Charlie: I share data between them. I don't need workarounds, I have many ideas how I could write it without gevent + sh, but I want to know how I do it with it. The question is actualy more general: how do I patch subprocess if it is used in some external modules (like sh)?

Answer (score 2):

The `sh` module *does not* use the subprocess module. It simply and directly does an `os.fork` followed by an `os.execve`. It also manages its own pipes for input and output. Thus, anything done to the subprocess module has no effect on `sh`.

So the answer to your question is, no, patching subprocess and expecting it to have any impact on sh is not possible.

Comment: Ok, that's a good point. But the question stays: how can I replace/patch os.fork used in the sh module with gevent.fork?

Comment: If you're already using `gevent.money.patch_all`, then that's already being done. *But it nearly doesn't matter!* Because `sh` uses `os.execve` immediately after fork, most of what the patch does isn't necessary. (The exception is if you're already using libev child watchers and need to wait on these new children. This only applies to gevent 1.1)